# Host Command throwing error due to DNS issues?

Tags: kali-linux, dns

I am connected to the lab private network using VPN. However, when I do

Host Ip_address m getting following error.

```
Host x.x.x.x.in-addr.arpa. not found: 3(NXDOMAIN)
```

Quick googling told me that my name server address in /etc/resolv.conf file is 8.8.8.8 and 4.4.4.4 which is public dns address for the google. Hence I tried finding my DNS address and updated the reslov.conf with that address (private dns address)

Upon doing so I again tired executing host command but m still getting following error

```
;; connection timed out; no servers could be reached
```

output of resolv.conf

```
root@kali:~# cat /etc/resolv.conf
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 4.4.4.4
```

M not sure how to obtain my DNS server address tried following method but can’t see DNS address attaching screen shot

[image]

Comment: Have you tried using `nslookup`?

Comment: yup getting following error ..

Commad : nslookup 10.11.1.5
Error : Server:  8.8.8.8
Address: 8.8.8.8#53

** server can't find 5.1.11.10.in-addr.arpa: NXDOMAIN

Comment: @Nasir Riley I wanted to determine the hostname from an IP address

Comment: I'm going to guess that `reslov.conf`is a typo. It's still using Google's public DNS. Add the output of you `/etc/resolv.conf` file to your question.

Comment: Is there actually an rDNS entry for the address in question?

Comment: Please see the updated Question

Comment: Next time I'd suggest you don't obfuscate the IP address. If we seen it was a 10. address we could have immediately tools you that the Google DNS servers wouldn't be able to resolve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's your problem. You need to add your internal DNS server to your `/etc/resolv.conf` file.

Google's public DNS servers can't resolve hostnames or IP addresses of your internal servers or workstations which most likely have private addresses aren't routable on the internet.

If you set the networking to DHCP then it should pick up your internal DNS server. You can then return it to static.

If that doesn't work, you can ask your IT department or find a computer which can resolve internal hostnames and use that to get the internal DNS server.

Comment: This answer should have more info. such as an explanation of why this addresses the issue.

Comment: Normally, I'd figure that would be known but in this case, you have a point so I'll add that info.

Answer (score 2):

Should probably point out that Google's two DNS servers are:
8.8.8.8
8.8.4.4

Not entirely related to your point, but still!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your valuable contribution i finally found the answer. I don’t know if this is the normal way, but I would like to share the approach. I was searching for *ipconfig /all* Linux equivalent command in order obtain DNS address for the local network in my kali machine

I knew from very beginning that I have to enter my local DNS address in  */etc/resolv.conf* file.

So what I did was I compromised the windows machine which was the same network and used *ipconfig /all* command on the compromised machine. From there I got the DNS address of the network which I updated In my */etc/resolv.conf* file and now *nslookup* command works like a charm.

Note to myself:

Try and search ipconfig /all command equivalent for Linux in order to get DNS address on local kali machine itself.

Comment: I added the same to my answer but it's good to see you got it working.

Comment: Look at `ifconfig` and `ip` under Linux.